# Manipulate plots in jupyter notebook

Tags: gnuplot, octave, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have an octave notebook and create a plot. That works fine, but I'd like to manipulate that plot by deleting and redrawing a line without redrawing the full plot:

```
delete(l3);
l3 = line(data(:,1), [ones(size(data,1),1) data(:,1)]*theta, 'color', 'red');
```

If I run this in an octave console this works fine, but when I try this in a notebook I get

```
error: delete: first argument must be a filename or graphics handle
```

So, is there a way to manipulate a plot in jupyter notebook? Or can I open the plot in an x11 window or something and then manipulate it?